# How to run in parallel calculations inside a nested for cycle in Python to obtain a distance matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-multiprocessing, numba

I am computing a square distance matrix using a nested *for* in Python. However, the number of calculations required to obtain such matrix is gigantic, while little RAM is used for each single calculation. Is there a way to easily fasten the calculation by running in parallel several distance calculations at a time?

```
for n in id:
  df_ = df[df['id_label'] == n]
  smis = df_['origin']
  distance_matrix=[]
  for l1 in smis:
    f1 = lang.convert(l1)
    row=[]
    for l2 in smis:
      f2 = lang.convert(l2)
      row.append(get_distance(f1, f2))
    distance_matrix.append(row)
  distance_matrix=np.array(distance_matrix)
  df_["distances"]=distance_matrix.sum(axis=1)
  df_.to_csv(f"output_cluster_{n}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: 1) you can use `multiprocessing` package. 2) you can optimize by caching results of `lang.convert` 3) If `get_distance(f1, f2)` is the same as `get_distance(f2, f1)`  you can optimize using this fact as well.

Comment: @dankal444 thanks for the suggestion! It is really helpful, however I don't think it is sufficient to speed up the calculation to a reasonable time due to the size of the matrix. I think this could be a part of the asnwer, but still distances have to be calculated in parallel.

Comment: @dankal444 maybe another starting point could be to vectorize the initial data frame with numpy, but still it would be needed to run a few calculations in parallel.

Comment: Vectorizing would help a lot, I'm sure. If you have trouble with doing it with numpy, you can take a look at `numba` package. Sometimes it is not easy, but still much easier to convert things to numba-compatible code than to write complex vectorization. As for parallelization -> `multiprocessing` package

Comment: @dankal444, how many things do you know?

Comment: not as many as I would like :)

Comment: Note that `lang.convert` appears to be a function call to an external module. Numba cannot speed up this. The function needs to be re-implemented. Please tell us more about what `lang.convert` is supposed to do/return (what is this `lang` package in the first place) and share the code of `get_distance`. A minimal reproducible example would help us.

Comment: @JérômeRichard from time checkers inserted in the code, it appears that the more expensive calculation is the one regarding the distance. Therefore, multiprocessing should be more helpful in reduce the impact of time required for the calculations, as the preliminary steps of the for loops. Unfortunately, `get_distance` is a proprietary code.